# Is using a custom adapter to inflate Android listview with data from TreeMap acceptable?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-adapter, treemap

I have an collection of objects with such fields:

- `String` IDs that are formed as UUID
- `Date` date of creation
- `int` rating

  I would like to create a tabbed view that will contain representation of objects at `ListView` sorted by date of creation and rating on two tabs. Looks like because of `String` IDs and need to sort objects the best fit data structure to store those objects will be `TreeMap`. If object will be stored at `TreeMap`, I will have to implement two custom `Comparator`'s to sort them according to my needs and then pass the data to `Listview`'s `Adapter` like shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32569709/inflate-listview-with-treemap-data-custom-adapter).

I would like to know

1. Is this an acceptable approach?
2. If not, which approach will be better?

Comment: I don't understand why you need to useTreeMap, can't you simply sort the data on the basis of the field using ArrayList/List and using custom Comparator?

Comment: ListView is based on numeric IDs. I have to compare items of 2 collections from different sources and update enries with same IDs if change detected.It seems I cannot compare entities with `String` IDs using List.

Comment: If I am not wrong what you want to do is to have two lists one in each fragment, one of which is sorted by date and the other rating? Right?

Comment: Let me clarify. I have 2 datasets of mentioned objects which need to be merged. If there is a collision (object with same ID), I select object with a latest date of creation. Then resulting dataset has to be passed to fragments to show entities sorted according to fragment's purpose (e. g. sorted by date or rating). Fragments may use one adapter or two — that does not matter.